# Multi nested FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model:

```
public class Stredisko
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubStredisko> Pracoviska { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubStredisko> Dohodari { get; set; }
}
public class SubStredisko
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public VyplatnePasky VyplatnaPaska { get; set; }
    public MzdoveNaklady MzdoveNaklady { get; set; }
    public Poistne Poistne { get; set; }
}
```

I am now trying to run a super simple LINQ query which should return first element which matches the following condition:

```
var sStredisko = Strediska.FirstOrDefault(
                    n => n.Pracoviska.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "somename"));
```

I Run this condition against: `ObservableCollection<Stredisko> Strediska`

However for unknown reason (to me) it gives me the following error:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'SubStredisko' to 'bool'**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what you're doing wrong

Comment: I just could not understand why there is a conversion to bool, when I am trying simply to retrieve an element

Comment: You can look at the method's documentation if you want to see the types of its arguments and to find information about why it accepts them, along with examples of how to provide them.  Of course, you are already providing a function that computes a boolean in the inner `FirstOrDefault` call, so presumably you do already understand that it accepts a function that provides a condition, a.k.a. a boolean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [`Enumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var sStredisko = Strediska.FirstOrDefault(
                              n => n.Pracoviska.Any(x => x.Name == "somename"));
```

`FirstOrDefault` will yield the first element that matches the predicate. You want to match against the first element and yield a `bool` indicating the match has been found, which is what `Any` does.

Answer (score 1):

Partially related to OP's question, this is what I was searching when I found this question:
I needed to actually get the nested object instead of the top one.

So re-using OP's model it would look like this:

```csharp
var sSubStredisko = Strediska
    .Select(n => n.Pracoviska.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "somename"))
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s != null);
```

Because of LINQ's deferred execution this won't loop twice but will just return the first nested element it will find (or none).

Comment: This is easier: `Strediska.SelectMany(n => n.Pracoviska).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "somename")`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return the nested item rather than the parent, you can first flatten the list:

```
var id = 123;

var subList = ParentList.SelectMany(all => all.SubList.SelectMany(all => all.SubListItem));

if(subList.Any())
{
     var childItem = subList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
}
```

This will work with nested items inside of nested items.